# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'field list' (laravel)

Tags: laravel

model

```
class Order extends Model {
    protected $attributes = [ 'status_fa' , 'type_fa' , 'delivery_type_fa' ];
.....
}
```

controller

```
$request->validate( [
        'category_id' => 'required|numeric' ,
        'file_id'     => 'required|numeric' ,
        'file_id'     => 'required|numeric' ,
        'origin'      => 'required|numeric' ,
        'goal'        => 'required|numeric' ,
        'subject'     => 'required' ,
        'time'        => 'required'
    ] );

    $order = Order::create( $request->only( 'category_id' , 'file_id' , 'origin' , 'goal' , 'subject' , 'description' , 'time' ) + [
            'user_id' => Auth::id()
        ] );

    return response( [ 'code' => 1 , 'order' => $order ] );
```

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'field list'

Comment: when remove "protected $attributes..." workd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I wrote a whole mistake. I should use this

```
protected $appends = [ 'status_fa' , 'type_fa' , 'delivery_type_fa' ];
```

Answer (score 0):

The $attributes array is to define the default values of the properties on your model (if required).  So, it should be something more like:

```
protected $attributes = [ 'status_fa' => 'Not Started', 'type_fa' => 'Large', 'delivery_type_fa' => 'Express' ];
```

However, I think you meant to use the $fillable array.  This defines which properties you want to make mass assignable.

```
protected $fillable = [ 'status_fa' , 'type_fa' , 'delivery_type_fa' ];
```

If the properties aren't listed in the $fillable array, they are not included in the request to save in the database.

Comment: public function getStatusFaAttribute() {
  $status = $this->attributes['status'];
  .......
 }

Comment: "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'status_fa' in 'field list'

Comment: @MahdiFarhadpour Do you have ‘status_fa’ in your migration?  Double check the column names in the table

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
class Order extends Model {
    protected $table= 'databse table name';
    protected $fillable = [ 'status_fa' , 'type_fa' , 'delivery_type_fa' ];
    protected $hidden = [id and those column that you dont wanna show in return request]
.....
}
```

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'field list'

Comment: Can i see the migration file?